# Fetch Column Names of a Table for Columns with Top 3 count

Tags: mysql, sql, database, count, datacolumn

I need the the Column Names in a table which are the Top Three Columns with the highest Count.

I am using mySQL:

I was able to get the count of the required columns using this query:

```
SELECT 
COUNT(unsafe_spaces_home) AS AH ,
COUNT(unsafe_spaces_school) AS SCH ,
COUNT(unsafe_spaces_market_place) AS MP ,
COUNT(unsafe_spaces_field_or_playground) AS PG ,
COUNT(unsafe_spaces_dumping_ground) AS DG ,
COUNT(unsafe_spaces_railway_station) AS RS ,
COUNT(unsafe_spaces_route_to_toilet) AS RT ,
COUNT(unsafe_spaces_toilet) AS ST ,
COUNT(unsafe_spaces_well_or_water_pump) AS WT ,
COUNT(unsafe_spaces_river_pond) AS RP ,
COUNT(unsafe_spaces_sewer) AS SS 
FROM formdata
```

I get the result as Follows:

```
AH  SCH MP  PG  DG  RS  RT  ST  WT  RP  SS
===========================================
 0  0   12  1   7   16  2   9   0   9   1
```

However I need the required result something like this:

```
  top_3_columns
 ================
   RS,MP,ST
```

How can I achieve this?

Comment: How come you want ST but not RP?

Comment: I was just trying to show an illustration for my example, I can have ST or RP but only columns with top three count

Comment: So you can also have both ST and RP? (Both having top three count.)

Comment: Yes I can have both...

Comment: Could you explain a little more about what it is, exactly, that you're counting?  Providing an argument to `COUNT()` counts the record if the argument evaluates to a non-`NULL` value, so performing such an operation over multiple columns in this fashion suggests you have a sparse table (which would perhaps be a good candidate for redesign using the [Entity–attribute–value model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entity%E2%80%93attribute%E2%80%93value_model), on which it would in turn be very simple to achieve this result with `GROUP BY attribute ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC LIMIT 3`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider column names as a,b,c,d,and e
Then you can use following query

```
select  tagName, value from 
(select  'a'  tagName, count(a)  value from formdata  UNION
select  'b'  tagName, count(b)  value from formdata  UNION
select   'c'  tagName, count(c)  value from formdata  UNION
select  'd'  tagName, count(d)  value from formdata  UNION
select   'e'  tagName, count(e)  value from formdata  
) 
as results
order by value desc 
limit 3;
```

Comment: Perfect...This is exactly how I used....Works like a charm....
Thanks....